# Show views page based on path

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have 3 node types:

- category
- subcategory
- product

These are all linked using Entity Reference module. All pages have a path (using autopath). What I want to do is show a view depending on the path.

So if I go to *categories/category-a/* I want to show all subcategories of that category
Same for the products. I want to show all products referenced based on the path.

I'm trying to make a view with `path = categories/%`

I set a "**contextual-filter:** `content: nid`" - "provide default value" - "raw value from url". But when I visit "*categories/category-a/*" I see the node with this path. The view isn't shown.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this [Article](http://banoodleland.com/2013/06/20/drupal-7-views-how-to-make-content-aware-view-blocks/)..

The contextual filter should be "`content:nid`"

The options should be set as follows...

- The Relationship should be your "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" relationship
- Under "When the filter value is NOT available" check "provide default value" and select "Content ID from URL"
- Apply changes and save view.

Comment: The problem is I don't see the view at all at the specified path...
I'm loading all nodes with type of subcategories, maybe I should make a view starting from categories?

Comment: When I change the path to "node/%" it works, but that's not what I want ;)

Comment: Glad you found it!!

Comment: It's working just fine when I show this view as a block, but what I want to do is show it as a page.

Comment: No, didn't find it at all ;) I want to "override" an existing path with my view, but that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Its not fair to override existing path but try using https://www.drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages to override it

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here. I have a "category" view, it shows all nodes of that type. Linked to the node. So I want to show a view instead of the node when clicking. What other way is there to link to the new view and show a nice looking path alias?